# How to decide the right tint for UISlider

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5, uislider

Say I have a picture. I want to set the UISlider's tint color to match the picture. If I do it the usual way by inputting the exact same number with the color value, what I get is a much lighter color.

So how do I set that up properly?

Comment: Have you found any solution?